# Flutter app bar background color from seed not working

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I am developing one app in Flutter. In this, I am trying to use `useMaterial3` in `ThemeData`. So I used below code to set color in `colorScheme`.

```
static ThemeData lightThemeData = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.red,
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      centerTitle: true,
      elevation: 2,
      titleTextStyle: textTheme.titleLarge,
    ),
  );
```

I have assigned above `lightThemeData` in `Main.dart` to theme property. AppBar not showing proper color when I run the app. Please check below screenshot.

[image]

It is not showing proper **Red Color**. Anyone know, why this is happening?

Flutter version: **3.0.1**

> Note: It is working on Flutter v2.10.5 but not on 3.0.1

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this for the full red experience:

```
static ThemeData lightThemeData = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
      seedColor: Colors.red,
      primary: Colors.red,
      secondary: Colors.red,
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.red,
      //other options
    ),
  );
```

Alternatively you can use fromSwatch like this:

```
static ThemeData lightThemeData = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.red,
      //other options
    ),
  );
```

But make sure to test every part of your app before using it because the documentation says:

> For historical reasons, instead of using a [colorSchemeSeed] or [colorScheme], you can provide either a [primaryColor] or [primarySwatch] to construct the [colorScheme], but the results will not be as complete as when using generation from a seed color.

I think fromSwatch is designed for Material Design 2.

*Following contains an external tool:*

For the absolute control over the colors there is a nice tool at https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom
From the left bar choose your colors, and export the result using the top right button(there is a Flutter option). Downloaded file contains the full schemes. You can override the colors you don't like and feed into the theme directly.

Answer (score 1):

The seed color is used directly to create the tonal palette for primary tones. The ColorScheme.primary is then assigned tone 40 for light mode and tone 80 for dark mode, from the same tonal palette. Neither of these colors will be an exact match for the "primary" seed color you used, it will be a color from a tonal palette that matches the seed color, since it is the primary one.

---

**Branding challange**

If you for branding purposes require it to exactly match the provided seed color, you can always override ColorScheme.primary you got with copyWith using the original seed color. And then use that ColorScheme as input to your apps ThemeData. A bit of an extra step, but it will work and look OK too, because for primaries the other colors will still match and be in sync with this color.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried but didn't help. If you add some code then that will be really helpful :)

Comment: if you add primary color instead of seed color it will give you the exact red color

Comment: I have tried but won't work. I removed colorScheme from themeData & added primaryColor.

Comment: remove it useMaterial3: true,

Comment: After removing it work. But I want to apply theme globally through out the app to widgets.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/main/material_3_demo     checkout this link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245404/discussion-between-ajay-and-tasnuva-tavasum-oshin).

Answer (score 0):

Your app generates a [ColorScheme] derived from the given seedColor.

Using the seedColor as a starting point, a set of tonal palettes are constructed. These tonal palettes are based on the Material 3 Color system and provide all the needed colors for a [ColorScheme].

Alternately, if you want any of your Widgets to have the exact same color as your provided seed color, you should provide it with background and foreground color, e.g.:

```
AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        foregroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
      ),
```

using this your appbar will look the exact colors as your seed color.